# Issue fadein effect on scroll down - $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to implement a fadein effect (on scroll down) on my wordpress site.
I have followed this tutorial: http://www.ordinarycoder.com/jquery-fade-content-scroll/
The issue is that when I copy paste the JS code between a  tag in the body of my page, it doesn't work (error console says that $ is not a function  ). What do I do wrong?
Thanks,

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll( function(){


        $('.fadeInBlock').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* Adjust the "200" to either have a delay or that the content starts fading a bit before you reach it  */
            bottom_of_window = bottom_of_window + 200;  

            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

            }
        }); 

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: None of the code past the second line is relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a JQuery function, have you included the JQuery library on your page?

Edit: Looking at your example, $ isn't being assigned to JQuery as an alias for some reason. Adding `var $ = jQuery` before your script fixes it, or changing `$` to reference the full name `jQuery` instead should fix it as well.